Need to be root with pyenv
I'm currently trying to use the method "add_hotkey" from the library keyboard.
When I do it, I have the error : "ImportError: You must be root to use this library on linux."
How can I bypass this properly ? (I don't want to install pyenv with my root user..)
I'm currently using python 3.12.5, with pyenv on ubuntu 24.04.1
import keyboard

keyboard.add_hotkey('a', lambda: print('test'))

Give me
ImportError: You must be root to use this library on linux.


You shouldn't have to install the library as root, "only" run the script as root.

(Also, this is a restriction of the library, nothing to do with pyenv. "To avoid depending on X, the Linux parts reads raw device files (/dev/input/input*) but this requires root.")

I know it is a library's restriction, my problem is i need this library, and i search how can i run it properly, without install pyenv or my python version on the root user.
When i sudo/i log as root, i don't have python or pyenv command available (neither the legacy python version)

They are likely available with the correct PATH settings. Check where Python and pyenv are installed while you are logged in as yourself. (pyenv is just a tool for managing different Python via PATH manipulations.)

I find a solution by passing on my command direcly my PATH and my VIRTUAL_ENV vars like that :
sudo env "PATH=$PATH VIRTUAL_ENV=$VIRTUAL_ENV" python test.py

Note: still less than ideal, but somewhat safer than running as root, is running as a user with the input group, assuming /dev/input/* are owned by root:input.
